# Azure timer trigger function using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am writing an Azure timer trigger using Python 3.x. I've got one such function running. I think I know to do it, create one from JS and then delete the 'index.js' and create a run.py. But this time, when I run my python function, I always got an error saying "No such file: index.js". I didn't see any bonds between the function and the 'index.js' file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://ourwayoflyf.com/running-python-code-on-azure-functions-app/

Comment: @LaurentMazuel Thank you so much but I am exactly following the same step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed [tutorial](https://ourwayoflyf.com/running-python-code-on-azure-functions-app/) in comment and reproduce your issue on my side though I refresh the portal.

[image]

However, after waiting for some time, it works. I suspect it's due to cache.

[image]

I suggest you creating python azure function on kudu directly. Just create `run.py` and `function.json` in new folder instead of changing the JS template.

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. After refreshing several times, my function was finally deployed.  Maybe I was just out of luck.

Answer (score 5):

We could add the python function from the Azure portal directly. If you want to create Timetrigger function,then we could change the trigger type

The following is my detail steps to create Python timetrigger function.

1.[Create an Azure function App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function#create-a-function-app)

2.Add a python function

[image]

[image]

3.Change the httptrigger to timetrigger

a. delete the httptrigger and http output
[image]

b. add the time trigger
[image]

4.Add the test code and test it from Azure portal.

[image]

The default version is 2.7.8. If you want to use python 3.x, you could follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/docs/custom-python-version.md) to update the python version.

5.Update the python version.

> a. Install extension for Azure function App
>
> b. Add Handler Mappings entry so as to use Python3.X via FastCGI

[image]

6.Test it from Azure portal

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed tutorial.  However, actually, my situation is more like Jay's. The Azure function just got stuck and after I refreshed the page for several times, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, run.py is recognized and run after I restart Azure Functions from the portal:
Azure Functions > Overview > Restart

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IHSb.png)