# How to trigger an alert notification of a long-running process in Azure Data Factory V2 using either Azure Monitor or ADF itself?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've been trying to find the best way to trigger an alert when an ADF task (i.e. CopyActivity or Stored Procedure Task) has been running for more than N hours, I wanted to use the Azure Monitor as it is one of the recommended notification services in Azure, however I have not been able to find a "Running" criteria, hence I had to play with the available criteria (Succeeded and Failed) and check this every N hours, however this is still not perfect as I don't know when the process started and we may run the process manually multiple times a day, is there any way you would recommend doing this? like a event-based notification that listens to some time variable and as soon as it is greater than the threshold triggers an email notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any way you would recommend doing this? like a event-based
>   notification that listens to some time variable and as soon as it is
>   greater than the threshold triggers an email notification?

Based on your requirements, I suggest you using [Azure Data Factory SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically#net) to monitor your pipelines and activities.

You could create a [time trigger Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer) which is triggered every N hours. In that trigger function :

1. You could list all [running activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.activityrunsoperationsextensions.querybypipelinerun?view=azure-dotnet) in data factory account.
2. Then loop them to monitor the [DurationInMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.activityrun.durationinms?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataFactory_Models_ActivityRun_DurationInMs) Property in [ActivityRun Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.activityrun?view=azure-dotnet) to check if any activity has been running for more than N hours and it's still In-Progress [status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.activityrun.status?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataFactory_Models_ActivityRun_Status).
3. Finally, send the email or kill the activity or do whatever you want.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I ended up doing something similar using the Python SDK and running a script from a VM, unfortunately Azure Functions do not support Python and I ended up using a VM with Python instead. However I'm following the same steps to catch this, it'd be nice to have an Azure Monitor criteria with Running :) . Thanks I will mark your recommendation as an anwer until I find a best one.

Comment: @SaulCruz You're welcome,BTW, as I know, azure function supports python code.Please refer  to my previous case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141674/azure-timer-trigger-function-using-python/51148801#51148801

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've actually tried to do this in the past but I'm not sure if I'm missing something but I can't find the Python language after creating my function app, the only available runtime stacks are Java, JavaScript and .NET, and when i select those I'm not able to find the python one, i will look into this again and edit the answer to provide more info. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest simple solution:
Kusto query for listing all pipeline runs where status is "Queued" and joining it on CorrelationId with those that we are not interested in - typically "Succeeded", "Failed". Join flavor **leftanti** does the job by "Returning all the records from the left side that don't have matches from the right." (as specified in MS documentation).
Next step would be to set your desired timeout value - it is 30m in the example code below.
Finally, you can configure Alert rule based on this query and get your email notification, or whatever you need.

*ADFPipelineRun
 | where Status == "Queued"
 | join kind=leftanti ( ADFPipelineRun
 | where Status in ("Failed", "Succeeded") )
 on CorrelationId
| where Start < ago(30m)*

I tested this only briefly, maybe there is something missing. I have an idea about adding other statuses to be removed from result - like "Cancelled".

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to exclude "Cancelled" runs? There doesn't seem to be a "Cancelled" status that shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Elapsed Time Metric:

- set max time for your pipeline
- set and alert in ADF with e.g. Elapsed Time Metric > 0 (so you will receive an e.g. email for any pipeline running longer than the benchmark set).

Documentation: [Deliver service level agreement for data pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-operationalize-pipelines)