# How to pass variable to ADF Execute Pipeline Activity?

Tags: etl, azure-data-factory

**Environment**:
I have around 100 pipelines that run on a number of triggers.

**Outcome:** I want to create a master pipeline that calls those 100 pipelines.

**Currently**, I've created a list of pipeline names and put them to an array. Then I was hoping to use forEach and execute pipeline activities to pass those names.

**Issue**, it seems that execute pipeline activity does not take variables or it is not obvious how to do it.

I do not want to create master pipeline manually as it can change often and I hope there must be better way to do it than manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the "Invoked pipeline" setting of the Execute Pipeline activity does not support a variable value: the Pipeline name must be known at design time. This makes sense when you consider parameter handling.

One way around this is to create an Azure Function to execute the pipeline. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085000/method-to-put-alerts-on-long-running-azure-data-factory-pipeline/59290603#59290603) has the .Net code I leverage in my pipeline management work. It's a  couple years old, so probably needs an update. If you need them to run sequentially, you'll need to build a larger framework to monitor and manage the executions, which is also discussed in that answer. There is a concurrency limit (~40 per pipeline, I believe), so you couldn't run all 100 simultaneously.