# AZURE | ADF | Logging the pipeline runs (execution details) in sql table

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-reporting

I want to design a feature in ADF pipeline by which I can store the execution details in sql table or CSV files. execution details for example at which activity pipeline failed pipeline name ,how many records got inserted updated in table by running the activity. this kind of information i want to log for multiple pipelines.

Thanks,
Amol

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manage this external to ADF. Here are a couple links that may help get you started:

[SO: Method to put alerts on long running azure data factory pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085000/method-to-put-alerts-on-long-running-azure-data-factory-pipeline/59290603#59290603)

This is a link to a presentation I gave earlier this year about creating an ADF Pipeline Management System:
www .youtube.com/watch?v=V8dLIIb6qGY

[NOTE: I'm not sure the rules on such self-promotional items, that's why this isn't a link.]